# Есть одна проблема, при включение внешнего модуля require('csv-parser') и require('fs'), выдаётся ошибка в консоли

Tags: javascript, csv, npm

При подключение внешних модулей require('csv-parser') и require('fs') в консоли вылезает ошибка ReferenceError: require is not defined. пакеты npm подключены.

```js
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];
console.log("hello");

fs.createReadStream('./filesCSV/fileCSV1.csv')
  .pipe(csv({separator:';'}))
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
  });
```

файл конфигурации:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\js\\parserCSV.js",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
]
```

Comment: Нет `require` - пробуй `import`...

Comment: всё равно не работает :(

Comment: А где вы это пытаетесь запустить? Не в браузере ведь?

Comment: да, я пытаюсь её в браузере запустить...)

Comment: В браузере это работать не будет. Импорты requare и import работают для nodejs или для сборщиков js типа webPack. Однако, серверные библиотеки импортировать и выполнить в клиентском браузере не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вы пытаетесь выполнить этот код в браузере, а не в среде Node.js. Функция require() является частью стандартной библиотеки Node.js, и она не будет работать в браузере. Вам необходимо создать проект Node.js и выполнить этот код в среде Node.js.

В файле конфигурации вам нужно добавить следующую опцию:

```
"runtimeExecutable": "node"
```

например:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\js\\parserCSV.js",
      "runtimeExecutable": "node", // добавлено
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

Это сообщает VS Code, чтобы он использовал node в качестве исполняемого файла для вашей программы